# SDR question: What is the number $m$ of different sets $P_k$ in $\mathcal P_n$ for a given $n$?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider elements of $Z_{2n}$, that is, numbers $0,1,2,\dots, 2n-1$. Let
$\mathcal P_n=\{ P_1,P_2,\dots, P_m\}$ be a collection of *unordered* *sets*, where each $P_k$ consists of $n$ ordered pairs $(a_i,b_i)$ with the following properties:

$(1)$ $A=\{ a_i| 1\leq i\leq n\}, B=\{ b_i| 1\leq i\leq n\}$, and
$A\cup B=\{0,1,2,\dots,2n-1\}$

$(2)$ For every $1\leq i\leq n$, we have $a_i < b_i$

$(3)$ For any $1\leq i,j\leq n, \ i\neq j$ we have $a_i < a_j < b_i$ if and only if   $a_i < b_j < b_i$

What is the number $m$ of different sets $P_k$ in $\mathcal P_n$ for a given $n$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How far have you gotten?

Answer (score 0):

Let $C_n$ be the number of such sets for a given $n$.  Clearly, $C_0=C_1=1.$  To establish a recurrence, we ask which number can be paired with $0.$   Suppose $(0,b)$ is one of the pairs.  Then in every other pair either both numbers are greater than $b$, or both are less than $b$.  That is, $b$ must be odd.  Further, the pairings of the numbers from $1$ to $b-1$ and the pairings of the numbers from $b+1$ to $2n-1$ must both obey rule $(3).$

Therefore, $$E_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}E_kE_{n-1-k}$$ and we recognize the recurrence for the [Catalan numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)  (look at the "First Proof" on the wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

With any $P_k\in \mathcal P_n$, we associate a legal sequence of $n$ open and $n$ closed parentheses by putting an open parentheses at position $a_i$ and a closed one at position $b_i$. Conversely, given any legal sequence of length $2n$, we can pair the positions of corresponding parentheses and the set of such pairs gives us an element of $\mathcal P_n$.
Therefore, $$\mid \mathcal P_n\mid= C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$$

Footnotes:
1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number